# How to add hyperlink to div class inside span?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Please refer to the code below. Can anyone tell me how to add a hyperlink to each image so when hovered over and clicked it will go to a new web page, or a new window or whatever?

There are 15 images scrolling from right to left. The CSS code I used was something I found on the web which apparently creates the "illusion" of infinite scrolling by setting each image as a `<div class>` and grouping them inside a `<span>`. It does work correctly, the 15th image comes in on the right side of the screen just as it is going off the left side of the screen. The images themselves are specified in the CSS using "content: url".

I can add rules in CSS, e.g. to hover over each image and zoom in using 'transform: scale' (as has been done, but only for div.image1) and I have tried to create the hyperlinks by putting `<a href>` into each `<div>`, I tried using jquery script while referencing the `<div class>` name, tried using javascript the same way - but no luck yet.

BTW I am a total novice at web page building and so far this is the only way I have found (without paying somebody) to make the infinite scrolling work. If it requires that I achieve the infinite scrolling some other way I guess that's okay, and I might understand your alternate method if offered conceptually, but it's just as likely that I would only be able to use the advice if the code was written for me to copy.

Thanks,

Abe

```css
div.image1 {
   width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/privatehouse01-01C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image2 {
   width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/privatehouse01-02C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image3 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/privatehouse02-01C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image4 {
   width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/privatehouse02-02C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image5 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse01-01C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image6 {
   width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse01-02C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image7 {
   width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse02-01C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image8 {
   width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse02-02C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image9 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse02-03C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image10 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse02-04C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image11 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse02-05C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image12 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse03-01C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image13 {
   width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse03-02C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image14 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse03-03C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

div.image15 {
  width:100px;
   height:67px;
   content: url('images/duplexhouse04-01C.jpg');
   float: left;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.image1:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marquee--inner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.marquee {
  height: 67px;
  width: 1500px;
  border: 0px solid #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 200px auto;
}

.marquee--inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
}

/*.half {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}*/

span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%:
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery of Work</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#000000">

<div class="marquee">
<div class="marquee--inner">
<span>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
<div class="image3"></div>
<div class="image4"></div>
<div class="image5"></div>
<div class="image6"></div>
<div class="image7"></div>
<div class="image8"></div>
<div class="image9"></div>
<div class="image10"></div>
<div class="image11"></div>
<div class="image12"></div>
<div class="image13"></div>
<div class="image14"></div>
<div class="image15"></div>
</span>
<span>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
<div class="image3"></div>
<div class="image4"></div>
<div class="image5"></div>
<div class="image6"></div>
<div class="image7"></div>
<div class="image8"></div>
<div class="image9"></div>
<div class="image10"></div>
<div class="image11"></div>
<div class="image12"></div>
<div class="image13"></div>
<div class="image14"></div>
<div class="image15"></div>
</span>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: “I have tried to …” What was the result? How does your result differ from your expectation?

Comment: Grouping block elements (`DIV`) within inline elements (`SPAN`) is invalid HTML and might lead to render-quirks you might have not foreseen.

Comment: "What was the result? How does your result differ from your expectation?"    ----   There was no result. The page looked and operated as it had before, and clicking on the image did nothing.